# No puedo leer un archivo .txt en C++

Tags: c++, archivo

Soy completamente nuevo en C++, estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt y siempre me salta el if que tengo por si falla, ya intente de todo y sigue sin leer el archivo, ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

He intentado cambiar el archivo, en alguna parte leí que era con doble diagonal invertida y tampoco funciona puede que se lea un poco simplón pero soy novato y aun no entiendo múltiples funciones o librerías de C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;



void lectura()
{
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;

    archivo.open("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\Semestre 6\\Lenguajes y automatas\\c++\\holaMundo\\ejemplo1.txt", ios::in);

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);

    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){

        getline(archivo,texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }

    archivo.close();
}

int main (){

   lectura();
   system("pause");
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: ¿qué error te sale?

Comment: el siguiente, Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás te sirva este ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void lectura() {
    ifstream archivo("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\Semestre 6\\Lenguajes y automatas\\c++\\holaMundo\\ejemplo1.txt");
    string texto;
    if (archivo.is_open()) {
        while (getline(archivo, texto)) {
            cout << texto << endl;
        }
        archivo.close();
    } else {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    }
}

int main()
{
    lectura();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me fue muy útil el ejemplo, gracias